# ModifiedBy field in SharePoint Document library is always my name instead of the one who triggered the flow

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, power-automate, sharepoint-rest-api

I have a flow, that gets triggered when a file is created in the Documents. The flow will add a column to the document library. The problem is that the modified by field in the Document library always contains the value as my name, instead of showing the user who triggered the flow.

I have already followed [this article](http://johnliu.net/blog/2019/2/flowninja-hack-78-modifying-modified-by-and-modified-time-with-microsoft-flow) and seems like that is not working on my end.

[image]

After doing those changes, my flow runs fine without any error and giving an output as proceeding.

```
{
  "d": {
    "ValidateUpdateListItem": {
      "__metadata": {
        "type": "Collection(SP.ListItemFormUpdateValue)"
      },
      "results": [
        {
          "ErrorMessage": null,
          "FieldName": "Editor",
          "FieldValue": "[{\"Key\":\"i:0#.f|membership|nk@fdgfsgfs.de\"}]",
          "HasException": false,
          "ItemId": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

But there are no changes in the Document library, it still shows my name in the modified by column as I created the Flow. Even if this worked, I have another question that how can I dynamically find out and add who is triggering the Fow instead of giving a static editor claim in the first Compose step in the above image?

Anyone else faced this issue? Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think it is possible at the moment to dynamically find the current logged in user. you can check out this post

https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Flow-to-SharePoint-list-item-change-quot-Created-By-quot/td-p/93668

Answer (score 0):

I could solve this issue by using the REST API in the flow itself. This is what I did,

1. Get the user who called the flow
2. Update the Modify field by using the REST API in the flow itself

This [blog post](http://johnliu.net/blog/2019/2/flowninja-hack-78-modifying-modified-by-and-modified-time-with-microsoft-flow) will help.